# Cannot convert vector3 to collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 3D racing game on Unity and I am currently looking to program checkpoints. Right now I have hit a roadblock in which I can't convert vector3 to collider. Any advice?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter3D(Collider Checkpoint)
    {
        if (Checkpoint.tag == "Checkpoint")
        {
            Checkpoint = transform.position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"I can't convert vector3 to collider"_ - sadly just like the dream of _converting lead into gold,_ C# does not allow conversion from one type to another if there are no implicit or explicit conversion operators in place.  Perhaps yours is a typo?

Comment: Question: What exact behavior do you want in your game when collision happens? just ellaborate it a bit so we can help you out in it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoint is a Collider data type. Try it with Checkpoint.transform.position

Answer (score 0):

A [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.html) is not at all a [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html). I invite you to read the documentation for both types to understand better what each is used for.

As mentioned in another comment, if you want to access a Collider position, you should use Collider.transform.position (so

```
Checkpoint.transform.position
```

in your case). A Collider component should be attached to the object your rigidbody is supposed to collide to.
If you want the Collider to respond phisically to impacts, as mentioned in the documentation, you should attach a Rigidbody to it.